# Resultado instrução SQL

Tags: sql, group-concat

Olá! tenho uma tabela de um questionário, gostaria de ter um resultado agrupado por "propriedade", fazendo um GROUP_CONCAT nas "respostas", segundo o modelo abaixo:

propriedade |  pergunta |  respostas
    10      |      1    |  arroz, feijão
    10      |      2    |  arroz, feijão, milho
    11      |      1    |  milho

Segue o sql da tabela
propriedade  | pergunta |  respostas
    10     |      1   |   arroz
    10     |      1   |   feijão
    10     |       2   |   arroz    
    10     |       2    |  feijão
    10     |       2   |   milho
    11     |       1   |   milho

Comment: Como está sua query? Você já tentou e não deu certo?

Comment: já tentei, usei exemplos mas não deu certo... usei GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT campo)

Comment: Mas qual o problema? Ocorre algum erro? Qual o código SQL completo que você tentou?

Comment: Esta síntaxe muda conforme o BD.

Comment: SELECT propriedade, pergunta, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT resposta) FROM questionario GROUP BY propriedade

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função STUFF do SQL Server: A função STUFF insere uma cadeia de caracteres em outra cadeia de caracteres. Ela exclui um comprimento especificado de caracteres da primeira cadeia de caracteres na posição inicial e, em seguida, insere a segunda cadeia de caracteres na primeira, na posição inicial.
Parâmetros:
character_expression: É uma expressão de dados de caractere. character_expression pode ser uma constante, variável ou coluna de caracteres ou de dados binários.

start: É um valor de inteiro que especifica o local para iniciar a exclusão e a inserção. Se start ou length for negativo, uma cadeia de caracteres nula será retornada. Se start for mais longo que a primeira character_expression, uma cadeia de caracteres nula será retornada. start pode ser do tipo bigint.

length: É um inteiro que especifica o número de caracteres a serem excluídos. Se length for mais longo que a primeira character_expression, a exclusão acontecerá até o último caractere na última character_expression. length pode ser do tipo bigint.

Sintaxe Função STUFF:
STUFF ( character_expression , start , length ,character_expression )

No seu caso ficaria algo assim:

```
with tab as
(
select 10 as id, 1 as cod, 'arroz' as descricao
union
select 10 as id, 1 as cod, 'feijão' as descricao
union
select 10 as id, 2 as cod, 'arroz' as descricao
union
select 10 as id, 2 as cod, 'feijão' as descricao
union
select 10 as id, 2 as cod, 'milho' as descricao
union
select 11 as id, 1 as cod, 'milho' as descricao
)
SELECT T1.id, T1.cod, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, T2.descricao)
                             FROM tab T2
                             WHERE T1.id = T2.id and t1.cod = T2.cod
                             ORDER BY T1.id
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS id_descri
FROM tab T1
GROUP BY T1.id, T1.cod
order by T1.id, T1.cod
```